# loop to set variables as worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hello my problem is the following:
I use to declare for example ws as worksheet and then set it to a specific worksheet. This way when I type the dot after ws I get suggestions for the methods that can be used.

Now I have a workbook with a lot of worksheet and I would like to be able to set each one of them to a different worksheet.

Do you think is it possible to achieve with a loop? thanks

I tried something like 
EDIT

```
Dim x as Worksheet 
for i=1 to 50
    x = "ws" & i
    set x = thisworkbook.Sheets(i)
Next
```

But it does't work
Thak you to everyone for your help

Comment: So you want to put the variable name in a variable?  ummm...  Maybe consider using an array of sheets.  Dim an variable as an array of variant, and set each index of the array to a sheet?  What's the point of that, though, if the sheets are already in an array (i.e. the workbook).  but you can loop through the sheets with a for each sh in sheets kind of thing.  Or, you can just use the codenames of the sheets as variables.  or create a dictionary, with the "variable name" as the key.

Comment: Please show us the declarations for these variables, it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve with just bogus code and "it doesn't work".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I admit I have not been very clear .. I am sorry for that. The point of doing this is to be able to use intellisense for every worksheet in the workbook. And since I can't loop through the sheets it very useful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or this way:

```
    Sub AssignWSobjectsToWorksheets()

        Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
        Dim ws() As Worksheet

        n = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

        ReDim ws(1 To n)

        For i = 1 To n
            Set ws(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Note that **Sheets** is the collection of all tabs(e.g. including charts), **Worksheets** just of spreadsheets

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array for this:

```
Dim n
Dim ws() as Worksheet

n = 50

Redim ws(1 to n)

for i = 1 to n
    set ws(i) = thisworkbook.Sheets(i)
Next
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer .. I am new to vba and I didn't know I could dim an array as worksheet