# VBA For Loop will only work on specific sheet

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have the below code that pulls out specific data from the spreadsheet and formats it into a table. Both *for loops* work, however the first one will only work if I'm on `Sheet1` and the second one will only work if I'm on `Sheet2`.

I can't work out how to rewrite it to make both sections of code work anywhere in the spreadsheet. Preferably from `Sheet1` if it had to be.

```
Sub MakeMyTable()

Dim Col As Variant
Dim Col2 As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long

Col = "D"
Col2 = "A"
StartRow = 1
X = 3    

'This with pulls the formatted data into totals into Sheet2

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    For R = StartRow + 1 To LastRow2 + 1 Step 1
        If .Cells(R, Col) = "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, "A").Value = "Project Cost Centers Costs At " & Date
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, "A").Value = .Cells(R - 1, Col).Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, "B").Value = .Cells(R - 1, "F").Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, "C").Value = .Cells(R, "P").Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, "C").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        X = X + 1
        End If
    Next R
End With

' This with finds any cell that has "RX04F.029.038" in it and moves it to the 
' bottom of the table.

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, Col2).End(xlUp).Row
    For R = LastRow2 To StartRow + 2 Step -1
            If InStr(1, Cells(R, Col2).Value, "RX04F.029.038") > 0 Then
            Rows(R).Cut
            Rows(LastRow2 + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            R = R + 1
            LastRow2 = LastRow2 - 1             
        End If
    Next R
End With




End Sub
```

Comment: change the bits which say Sheets("Sheet2") or  Sheets("Sheet1")  to use a sheet variable and pass that variable to the With myVar...

Comment: Loop an array of sheet variables if you want to pass multiple different sheets  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268377/loop-to-set-variables-as-worksheet

Comment: You also need to properly link your `With` statement to the ranges you use. For example, you have `With Sheets("Sheet2")` but them don't link the `lastRow2 = Cells().Row` to it.  Do this for all such instances: `LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count,Col2).End(xlUp).Row`.  Otherwise, any use of a range will occur on the ActiveSheet, whatever that may be.

Comment: `Qualify` your sheets (just do a search for `qualify sheets in vba`). Further more, when qualifying sheets, please don't use Selected sheet or active sheet

Comment: A couple things: **With** loops aren't a thing; you're actually working with **For** loops. **With** simply, *"Executes a series of statements on a single object..."*. *X* isn't declared, and *LastRow* actually seems to be used as *LastRow2*. With that being said, can you show us your data set? That'll help us be able to recreate your problem.

Comment: Replace `If InStr(1, Cells(R, Col2).Value, "RX04F.029.038") > 0 Then` witth `If InStr(1, .Cells(R, Col2).Value, "RX04F.029.038") > 0 Then`. Spot the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to properly link your With statement to the ranges you use. For example, you have With `Sheets("Sheet2")` but them don't link the `lastRow2 = Cells().Row` to it. Do this for all such instances: `LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count,Col2).End(xlUp).Row.` Otherwise, any use of a range will occur on the ActiveSheet, whatever that may be. – BruceWayne 3 mins ago

Edit: BruceWayne gave me the answer I need in the comments but cant mark it as an answer so this is the best I could do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the sheet names to what you want.

Or you can swap:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
```

for

```
With ActiveSheet
```

if you want to run the loops on the active sheet.